# My partition (hard disk) is not visible in file explorer

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, windows-explorer

Partition is visible in Disk Management and is assigned the letter E.

[image: disk manager]

But when you open File Explorer the drive E: doesn't show up.

[image: file explorer]

If I type E:\ in File Explorer's address bar, the content of the partition appears normally.

[image: file explorer 2]

Drive is not Hidden and Folder Options is set to show Hidden files.

This happened quite suddenly without major changes to the system. OS is Windows 7 x64.

Maybe a registry problem ?

Comment: Please provide the value of `NoDrives` at  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` in your registry

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didnt find NoDrives under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer.

Doing search there was a NoDrives in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Policies\Explorer, but the value was 0.

Another one in HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-848..\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Policies\Explorer, but still 0.

Comment: The key under HKEY_USERS is probably the same you see under HKCU. Well, 0 means no hidden drives. Still, worth a try. :D

Answer (score 0):

On that computer management screen, assign a new/different drive letter to that drive. It should work after the change, if it works, you can change back the drive letter latter.

Comment: Hi, thx for the idea. I assigned it the letter F it still not visible.